# CSS selector for a select list that has a size attribute other than 1?

Tags: css

Is there a CSS selector I can use to target select lists that have a size attribute set to something other than 1? I need to not target size="1" or when no size attribute is set.

```
<p>Dont target this:</p> 
<select>
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select (multi)</option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<p>Do target this:</p>
<select size="5">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select (multi)</option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nrExe

Comment: Can't you add a class on the select elements you target ?

Comment: Could you explain why you wish to choose based on size and not an id / class selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified, for `select` elements **with** a size attribute which **isn't** 1:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/pd28h/1/)

```
select[size]:not([size='1']) {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... I need to not target size="1" or when no size attribute is set.

You need to target presence of the `size` attribute:

*Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Gfg7n/1/*

```
select[size] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or vice-versa:

```
select:not([size]) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I nee to target size="2", size="3", size="4" etc but not size="1".

Comment: I responded to the "or" part of your question: *or when no size attribute is set*. Anyways, SW4 has answered the other part of the question, and I see that you have accepted that. So cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
select[size*="5"]{
  background-color: #1f6053;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X76Jb/)

**html:**

```
    <p>Dont target this:</p> 
<select>
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select (multi)</option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<p>Do target this:</p>
<select size="5">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select (multi)</option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

**css:**

```
select[size*="5"]{
  background-color: #1f6053;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt quite conform to `have a size attribute set to something other than 1` - this effectively selects all select elements with a size attribute which contains a 5

Comment: I will agree with you @SW4 :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you put `size` attribute only on `select` element that have **2 and more options**, you could do something like that :

```
select[size] {
  /* :) */
}
```